# Why is nginx access.log failing?

Tags: linux, nginx, server, manjaro, arch

I try to use nginx on manjaro by typing up `nginx` on the terminal, but this comes up:`open() "/var/log/nginx/access.log" failed (21: Is a directory)`. I ran `sudo nginx -t` and `sudo systemctl start nginx.service` and they both said the same thing. Is there something I can do to remedy this issue? Also to add, I used `systemctl status nginx.service` and it says under `Loaded:` `nginx.service` and `vendor preset` were disabled. Is this important?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually made access.log into a directory. Try `rm -rf /var/log/nginx/access.log` and then `nginx -t` and restart NGINX afterwards

Comment: Thank you so much. For some reason ```access.log``` was installed as a directory.